# 'Flat' FlexVPN Network Design with multi gateways

Tags: cisco, vpn, design

The use case is a meshed ip radio network where the radio's move around alot. Multiple gateway's (FlexVPN Spokes) are statically located to re-bridge the meshed radio network when the radio's travel to another site. All the radio's need to be in the same subnet to manage as they move past the different gateways/spokes.

I'm trying design this the best way to prevent headaches in the future and also not congest the meshed radio network.

Comment: The only solution i can think of is using a L2TP over the FlexVPN if you wanna use the same subnet everywhere. FlexVPN Spokes (routers) would then have different "Transport" networks, where you would build L2TP tunnels to centrally connect all the locations into one big L2 network. EDIT: just saw that this same-ish question has been posted already.

Answer (score 3):

Bridging across WAN (VPN) links is a really bad idea and should be avoided wherever possible. What kind of L2 tunneling you use doesn't really matter, the differences are marginal.

Since you seem to use static addresses currently, I'd propose to switch to dynamic DHCP addresses - this of course requires some kind of registry service to allow the nodes to find each other.

One rather simple way is to have each node/radio register its name in DNS and use DNS names throughout instead of the static IP addresses that would require a flat network.

If each radio creates its own VPN link to a central location you can forget about all this as the VPN subnet already forms an overlay network that doesn't suffer from (physical) L2 bridging of entire segments.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I used L2TPv3 over Flexvpn to with a BVI at the Hub to fix this issue.